# Contradiction in the limit definition!

Tags: calculus

I am suspicious about the definition of the limit.

Let $f$ be a function defined on some open interval that contains a number $a$, except possibly at a itself. Then we say that the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $a$ is $L$.

If the distance between $f(x)$ and the limit $L$ is less than any positive number $\epsilon$, then by a theorem known in real analysis it is must be $0$.
Then, $f(x)$ must equal $L$, but this a contradiction with the fact that most functions have different values for different “x”. For example, $f(x) = x$
has unique $f(x)$ for each $x$ and by the definition, the point $a$ is excluded.

Have fun in answering!

Comment: Alas, I cannot make any sense of this.

Comment: Perhaps you are just grossly misunderstanding the definitions.  A function has a defined limit in the codomain, what we'll call $L$, at a specific value from the domain, we'll temporarily call $a$, iff for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that if $0<|x-a|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.  Next, we say that a function is continuous *at* $a$ iff a limit exists at $a$ and $f(a)$ is equal to that limit, i.e. $f(a)=L$.  Now... a function is called continuous iff for *every* value in the domain, a limit exists for each and further the limit for each is equal to the functions value.

Comment: Of course the limit can and will vary based on which value in the domain you are looking at, the limit does not need to be the same for each, nor does anything else need to be the same for each.  It sounds like you are somehow under the impression that everything must equal $L$ where $L$ is a constant unchanging number...

Comment: The definition of limit contains $0 < |x-a| < \delta$, not $|x-a| < \delta$.  This makes a big difference.

Comment: You simply misunderstand the "theorem known in real analysis". The theorem is about two specific/fixed/constant real numbers. Here the $f(x) $ is itself dependent on $\epsilon $ so that $f(x) $ does not represent a fixed number rather it varies with $x$. If the function were constant then the theorem would apply and the function would indeed be equal to $L$.

Answer (score 4):

Your confusion is in the quantifiers. The definition does *not* say that $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$. It says that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that *if* $0<|x-a|<\delta$ *then* $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon|$.

So the set of $x$ such that the definition implies that $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ *depends on $\epsilon$.* Nothing here implies that there exists $x$ siuch that $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: For “every” epsilon, the remaining of the definition holds. So, for every epsilon the distance is less than that epsilon. Isn’t it?

Comment: @math_fun No, of course not. Try reading what I wrote above.

Answer (score 0):

The distance is not less than any positive number.
It can be made as small as we want.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between $f(x)$ and $L$ is **not** infinitesimal. That's not what the definition says.

We write $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=L$ if for any $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that for $x$ within $\delta$ of $a$ (other than $a$ itself) we have $f(x)$ is within $\epsilon$ of $L$.

The crucial observation is **$\delta$ depends on $\epsilon$**. There's no one $\delta$ that works for *every* positive $\epsilon$. For example, let $f(x)=3x$ and $a=0$. Of course we should have $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=0$. And indeed we do. For example:

- For $\epsilon=1$, we can take $\delta={1\over 3}$: **if $x$ is within ${1\over 3}$ of $0$, then $f(x)$ is within $1$ of $L$.**
- For $\epsilon={1\over 2}$, we can take $\delta={1\over 6}$: **if $x$ is within ${1\over 6}$ of $0$, then $f(x)$ is within $1\over 2$ of $L$.**
- More generally, for any specific $\epsilon>0$, we can find an appropriate $\delta$ - the natural choice of course being $\delta={\epsilon\over 3}$. *(That said, we could be silly and set (for example) $\delta={\epsilon\over 216}$; we never get into trouble by making $\delta$ smaller than it needs to be, as long as it stays positive.)*.